# How do I get a VM Image from Azure in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Previously in Powershell I was using the Get-AzureVMImage cmd-let to retrieve a VM Image I had generated. I would store the image an as object to build a VM with New-AzureQuickVM. Below is a code snippet:

```
$image = Get-AzureVMImage | where { $_.Imagename -like $basicImageNames[$n] } | Sort-Object -Descending -Property PublishedDate | Select-Object -First 1 -OutVariable image
```

Now with the new AzureRM Powershell Module, the majority of the cmd-lets for Powershell management have been renamed or deprecated. Get-AzureVMImage.

I've attempted to use Get-AzureRmImage, but it doesn't list any of my VM Images.

I've also attempted to use Get-AzureRmVMImage, but this appears to be valid only for official published images, and not my user generated ones.

Does anyone know of an equivalent cmd-let to the deprecated Get-AzureVMImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your describe, I think you have created a Classic Image ,right? 
As I known, Classic image can only be used to create classic VM. Also, you **cannot using Azure RM powershell to get a Classic Image** and to create a classic VM.

So, I suggest you can go to **Azure portal > VM images(classic)> find your generated Image>Create VM** . Or  you can also **use Azure SM powershell to login your Azure Classic Account** and then use Get-Azure VM image.

See more details about **Get-AzureVMImage** in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azurevmimage?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

See more details about **Get-AzureRmImage** in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/get-azurermimage?view=azurermps-4.4.0).

Comment: Yes, the images are legacy Classic Images. Thanks for letting me know Azure RM powershell won't work in this case. I'll use Azure SM powershell instead.